# How to launch the python selenium script on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, geckodriver

I'm trying to launch it after `xvfb-run firefox` but it returns me [these mistakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbsEM.jpg).
When I try to launch it with `python3` command it returns me `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/druid/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.31.0/geckodriver'`

Here's a piece of my code:
import time

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def main():
    #options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: can you share the selenium code, did you instal gecko driver?

Comment: @anarchy I used the webdriver_manager package

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu 22?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus it's 18.04

Comment: did you try to create this directory before running code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this and try to run you code again,

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver
```

If that doesn't work.

You can try to download the gecko driver manually. Then change the directory to the location of where you downloaded it to. Download from here, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases unzip. Then change your code to this,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def main():
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    #options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--headless")

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/druid/path/to/geckodriver', options=options)
```

Your executable path is where you placed the geckodriver executable.

I have updated the code to start in headless mode because you mentioned you were getting an error as you are running this on a server.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248682/discussion-on-answer-by-anarchy-how-to-launch-the-python-selenium-script-on-ubun).